# Possible to Run a Java GUI on a computer from an Android?

Tags: java, android

If an Android device were connected to a computer via USB charger, would it be possible to launch a java GUI on the computer from the device (i.e. by pressing a button in an android app)?

Also, would this be a platform dependency nightmare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible yes, not easy though and there may be some platform issues.

You would already need to have something running on the destination computer which detected the message from Android and then launched the GUI.

In fact the simplest way to do that may be to ignore the USB and just do the whole thing over the network.

You can't just run arbitrary code on the computer by plugging the phone in though, if you think about it that would be a massive security hole!

Comment: Well the winter bash hats are overlaping "answered 15 mins ago" :P
Now i realise , they arent changing our Display Picture they are using script to overlay the hat on our display pic :P

Sorry for off topic comment , but coudlnt resist

Comment: Lol, yah. It's obvious why they would do it that way - they only need one Image stored per hat, rather than having to store a modified profile picture for every hatted user.